# Execution time of object initialization in a tight loop

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, benchmarking

I have three methods in c# that runs the same code but with a little bit difference, my first code block is

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
object o = new object();
s.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    o.ToString();
    o.GetType();
    o.GetHashCode();
}
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds); //3100ms
```

and this costs 3100ms to run. Then if I make the object initialization inside the for that is increased to 7200ms my code block looks like this;

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    object o = new object();
    o.ToString();
    o.GetType();
    o.GetHashCode();
}
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);//7200ms
```

However, if I initialize my object but not using any method inside this costs for 652ms. And my code is just like this one,

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    object o = new object();
}
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);//625ms
```

So I wonder, 3100ms + 625ms is not comparable with 7200ms. What causes that much difference between the first two?

Comment: was this compiled in release mode and run outside of VS ?

Comment: How about the call to your 3 `object` methods?

Comment: @Menahem : I call this without debugging.

Comment: @ken2k : that dont change anything actually, records stills the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second block, you're calling `GetHashCode()` on lots of new objects. From what I remember, the first time a non-overridden `GetHashCode()` method is called on an object, a syncblock is allocated for the object. That's relatively expensive, although subsequent calls to `GetHashCode` for the same object (as per your first code) are cheap.

So there are three things to bear in mind:

- Cost of object allocation (and any GC)
- Cost of the *first* call to a method
- Cost of *subsequent* calls to methods

That's a generalization of course - many methods take the same amount of time however many times you call them, and other ones may be slow for (say) the first 10 calls and fast thereafter. I believe that in the case of `GetHashCode()` it's "first call is expensive" territory though. Try it with a type which overrides `GetHashCode()` in some simple way and I suspect you'll find the time taken plummets.

Additionally it's possible that `GetType()` takes a while to construct the `Type` for `object` the very first time it's called - I'm not sure. Basically you're measuring a bunch of different things together here, which always leads to difficult analysis.

Comment: Any chance the compiler removes the allocation statement?

Comment: @Polity: I very much doubt it. Unless it had special knowledge that the `object` constructor couldn't throw an exception, it would be an invalid optimization.

Comment: @JonSkeet : thanks for a fast reply, and it really changed after I override the GetHashCode() method. But I don't think I understood the thing about "many methods take the same amount of time however many times you call them, and other ones may be slow for (say) the first 10 calls and fast thereafter"

Comment: @lazycoder: Well it entirely depends on what the method does. If it lazily does something expensive (as GetHashCode does) then the first time is more expensive. For some other cases, the expense will change over time (think of a cache) or there may be some fixed number of pre-allocated results, etc. Basically you can't assume that a method will always take the same time to run.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh I got it now, you were talking about the business logic inside then. anyhow, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would decompile the methods with Refactor or something like that and see the generated IL. Probably the answer is there.

Comment: some of the optimization will not be apparent in the IL eg. the instantiation will be there in both the 2nd and 3rd however since the assigned value is never used in the third example the optimizer have more options, so the IL alone is probably not enough